# Is there a conda (mamba) equivalent to pip install's `--root` path option?

Tags: pip, dockerfile, conda

### Background

I have a multi-stage Dockerfile for a JupyterLab image. There are three stages:

- `server`
- `kernel`: `mamba create -y -n /tmp/kernel-packages/myenv ...`
- `runner`:

```
FROM ... as runner
...

COPY --from=kernel /tmp/kernel-packages/ /opt/conda/envs
RUN conda config --append envs_dirs /opt/conda/envs/

...
```

### Problem

In the resulting image, [the preferred](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/) `python -m pip` works, but `pip` gives:

`bash: /opt/conda/envs/myenv/bin/pip: /tmp/kernel-packages/myenv/bin/python3.9: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

The reason is that `pip` has `#!/tmp/kernel-packages/myenv/bin/python3.9` as its shebang.

### Expected

A behaviour like `pip install --root /tmp/server-packages ...`, which works perfectly fine in a `COPY --from=server /tmp/server-packages /`.

### Additional information

Additionally, some other binaries, like `curl` or `papermill` also have wrong paths hardcoded by `conda`. I've read about [Anaconda | Moving Conda Environments](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/moving-conda-environments), but it seems like overkill to use `conda-pack` and `conda-unpack`.

### Workaround

Simply create an env by name: `mamba create -y -n myenv` and then in the `runner` stage `COPY --from=kernel /opt/conda/envs /opt/conda/envs`.

### Question

**Is there a Conda (Mamba) equivalent to `pip install`'s `--root` option?** I'm not looking for a solution to the stated problem as I have  I have already found a way that works for me. My interest is purely in the functionality of the `conda` binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `--prefix` argument is the equivalent - just that some Conda packages use hardcoded paths, hence the issue you encounter.

### `conda-prefix-replacement`

To properly move a Conda environment to a new prefix via a COPY operation one would need to run the `conda-prefix-replacement` tool (a.k.a., `cpr`) to ensure that all files with hardcoded paths get updated to the new location. Presumably, `conda-pack` is doing a similar thing, just under-the-hood.

For your purposes, you might consider pre-running `cpr` on the environment(s) in the kernel image so that they are ready to work in the deployed location. Though that would mean always COPYing to the same location.

See [the `cpr` repository](https://github.com/conda/conda-prefix-replacement) for details on use.