# Incorrect Conda path after linux system migration

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

Our server was updated to use the NFS system, and the previous `/scratch` path is now mapped to `/local/scratch`. My anaconda3 was installed under `/scratch/xxx/anaconda3`, which basically means it is now under `/local/scratch/xxx/anaconda3`. Intuitively, I have updated the `PATH` variable in `.bash_profile`, and running `which conda` actually gives me

```
/local/scratch/xxx/anaconda3/bin/conda
```

However, when I actually tried to run `$conda`, the system reports the error below:

```
-bash: /scratch/xxx/anaconda3/bin/conda: No such file or directory
```

which is quite weird and indicates an inconsistency with the result returned by `which conda`.
In addition, I tried to directly `cd` into `/local/scratch/xxx/anaconda3/bin/` and execute `$./conda`. It reports

```
-bash: ./conda: /scratch/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

My wild guess is that in addition to the environment variable in `.bash_profile`, there are some internal settings of anaconda stored elsewhere, because the system actually knows the right path for python, while conda tries to execute python from the old path (i.e., `/scratch/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python` in the above error message). However, I couldn't seemingly find this file and change it to get things work.

Somehow, I feel this should be a common issue, however, I did not find any solutions from the internet. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you need CPR: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576019/570918

Comment: @merv I have posted my own answer with detailed instructions, but you are welcome to post your answer so I can accept yours (the credits are yours :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed my issue using `cpr` (credits to @merv). Here I post the detailed instructions, so if some one has the same problem, he/she can almost just follow them to get things fixed.

**1. Installation**

According to [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/conda-prefix-replacement), the recommended command to install `cpr` is

```
$ conda install -c anaconda conda-prefix-replacement
```

You may find this to be actually very awkward; the reason we need `cpr` is that our `conda` is broken due to the prefix issue, if we can run `conda` command to install `cpr`, then why should we need `cpr`?

Instead, we may install `cpr` directly from github:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/conda/conda-prefix-replacement.git
$ cd conda-prefix-replacement
$ python setup.py install
```

**2. Rehome**

After installation, running the `rehome` command to fix the prefix issue is quite straightforward. Say your anaconda is moving from `path_A` to `path_B`, simply do

```
$ cpr rehome path_B --old-prefix path_A
```

In my case, the command should be

```
$ cpr rehome /local/scratch/xxx/anaconda3 --old-prefix /scratch/xxx/anaconda3
```

After running the `cpr` command, exit the terminal and re-login. Everything should be good now!

Comment: This is great! I’ve actually never been in a situation that I needed it - just recognize situations where it applies -, so happy to see a report of firsthand use. I’ll note that the reason it is needed is because Conda does some amazing heavy lifting under-the-hood to minimize duplicate files by using hardlinks. So, this is a patching tool to maintain the complex file system integrity.